# Eigen: Block transpose?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am not exactly sure how to phrase this question...

I have a matrix of data that looks like this

```
A = [  x(0,0) , ...,  x(0,m-1)  ]
    [    ...  , ...,     ....   ]
    [ x(n-1,0), ..., x(n-1,m-1) ]
```

where `x` is itself a vector of size `p x 1`. So the matrix is of size `pn x m`.

I need a reference to the matrix

```
B = [  x(0,0) , ...,  x(n-1,0)  ]
    [    ...  , ...,     ....   ]
    [ x(0,m-1), ..., x(n-1,m-1) ]
```

If `x` were transposed in the above equation, then clearly, we would have that `B = A^T`, but that is not the case. So it is unclear how I can create the above matrix.

Furthermore, if I just needed a copy of the matrix `B`, then I could construct it using some `block` operations. However, I need a reference. Any idea how I would do that?

Part of the problem seems to be this:

If the data in `A` is stored in contiguous memory, then the references in `B` are referencing the data in a non-contiguous way. For instance, I don't think you could construct `B` using a stride.

I use the `Map` function extensively for reshaping, but I just don't see how to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but at the cost of expensive integer divisions and modulo (those can be optimized if `p` is known at compile time).

So the simplest is to use a `NullaryExpr` to transform the row/column indices as described [there](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org//dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html). In your case, the respective nullary functor will implement something like this:

```
const typename ArgType::Scalar& operator() (Index row, Index col) const {
  return m_arg(col/p, row*p + col%p);
}
```

However, write access won't be possible. This is because a `NullaryExpr` is not supposed to be writable. It has been designed for procedural matrices like Zero, Ones, Identity, Random, etc.

Comment: `p` is indeed known at compile time.

Comment: Why won't write access be possible?

Comment: Then make sure the compiler can know that and the compiler will do the optimizations for you ;)